# Getting "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'connection' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Im new in python and im getting the above error by trying to assign a connection variable to a function in a different .py file

i've tried to set connection as none but didnt solve my issue

## views.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from FlaskWebProject1 import app

import json
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import FlaskWebProject1.db 



@app.route('/')
@app.route('/users')
def users():

  try: 
    lstUsers = ''

    #connect to DB
    connection = db.get_connection()

    if connection.is_connected():
        #db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
        #print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)
        cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
        cursor.execute("select * from users;")
        record = cursor.fetchall()
        lstUsers = record       
        #print("Your connected to database: ", record)
  except Error as e:
         print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e) 
  finally:
        if (connection.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")

  return render_template('users.html',
    title = 'Users Page', 
    users = lstUsers)
```

## db.py

```
_connection = None

def get_connection():
    global _connection
    if not _connection:
        _connection = mysql.connector.connect(user="bla@bla", 
                       password='bla', 
                       host="mysql.database.azure.com", 
                       port=3306, 
                       database='testdb')
        return _connection

# List of stuff accessible to importers of this module. Just in case
__all__ = [ 'getConnection' ]
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\views.py",
>   line 24, in users
>       connection = db.get_connection() NameError: name 'db' is not defined
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1982, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.full_dispatch_request()   File "C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)   File "C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1517, in handle_user_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py",
>   line 33, in reraise
>       raise value   File "C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1598, in dispatch_request
>       return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint   File "C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\views.py",
>   line 37, in users
>       if (connection.is_connected()): UnboundLocalError: local variable 'connection' referenced before assignment
>   127.0.0.1 - - [09/Sep/2019 23:56:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [09/Sep/2019 23:56:55] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -

I expect to assign the connection variable in views.py file to the get_connection() that returns a connection in db.py and use the connection in order to connect to MySQL server with no issues

Comment: You need to show us all of the code, and the full stack trace.

Comment: ok, wait me a second please

Comment: i have added all the code

Comment: so now put full error mesage (starting at word "Traceback") There are other useful information.

Comment: done, i added it

Comment: error show `NameError: name 'db' is not defined` so it is your main problem. Because it can't find `db` so it can't run `get_connection()` and can't create `connection` and later it can't use variable `connection` and you get other error message.

Comment: you use `import FlaskWebProject1.db` so probably you have to use `FlaskWebProject1.db.get_connection()`

Comment: yes, that was the issue... as you mentioned instead of db.get_connection() use FlaskWebProject1.db.get_connection() and also inside db.py file I have to import mysql.connector again. Next time i will read full error message. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error shows

```
NameError: name 'db' is not defined`
```

so this is your main problem and source of other problems.

You have

```
import FlaskWebProject1.db
```

so you need `FlaskWebProject1.` in

```
connection = FlaskWebProject1.db.get_connection()
```

or you should import

```
from FlaskWebProject1 import db
```